# Toolbar and button not showing, showing beneath scrollview

Tags: android, button, scrollview

I can't seem to figure out why my toolbar and button for one of my activities is showing beneath the scroll view I created. The scroll view is within a constraint layout that is with an outer constraint layout. That could be the problem but I am not entirely sure. The button is outside of the scrollview but still within that constraint layout.

**activity_second.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    tools:context=".SecondActivitiy">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:background="@color/black"
            app:logo="@drawable/leftarrow4">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Create an account"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.1dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="76dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="30dp"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="Email address"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/museosans_500"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="Create Password"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:inputType="textPassword" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/museosans_500"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="Repeat password"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="22sp" />

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:background="@color/white"
                        android:inputType="textPassword" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/museosans_500"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Your password should have minimum of 8 characters and contain atleast one number, one uppercase and one lowercase letter. You can use special character."
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:onClick="createAccount"
            android:text="Next"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            style="Theme.Gflag.MaterialButton"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**AppBarLayout**

The code written below is shown in front.

Move `AppBarLayout` under the `ConstraintLayout`.

Or just constraint `ConstraintLayout` to `AppBarLayout`, So there's no overlapped area.

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/appBarLayout"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

**Button**

`Button` is disabled. Check this attribute.

```
android:enabled="true"
```